# cache external files eg, i.ytimg.com/vi/@code@/0.jpg with apache .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, caching, file, external, validation

As topic is it possible to set cache on external resources with htaccess.

I have some third party stuff on my site eg, google web elements and embedded youtube clips.

I want my google page speed to get higher.

error code from page speed:

The following resources are missing a cache validator.

```
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/-MfM1fVSFnM/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/-PxVKNJmw4M/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/3nxENc_msc0/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5Bra7rbGb7g/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5P76PKybW5o/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9l9BzKfI88o/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/E7hvBxMB4XI/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/IiocozLHFis/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/JIHohC8fydQ/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/P66uwFpmQSE/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/TXLTbARnRdU/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/bPBrRzckfEQ/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/dajcIH9YUuI/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/g4roerqw090/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/h1imBHP3DdA/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/hRvW5ndLLEk/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/kzahftbo6Qc/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/lta2U3hkC4k/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/n1o9bGF88HY/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/n3csJN0wXew/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/q0Xu-0moeew/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tPCDPKirZBM/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/uLxsPImMJmg/0.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/x33B_iBn2_M/0.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's up to them to cache it.

The best you could do would be to download them onto your server and then serve them, but that would be slower anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, setting cache settings for third parties is not possible unless you start passing  those resources through on your server as a proxy, which you usually don't want for reasons of speed and traffic.

As far as I can see, there's nothing you can do here.

Answer (score 0):

You could delay your Youtube videos from loading on the page until something like a holding image is clicked. This wouldn't cache these images when (or if) they are loaded, but they wouldn't detrimentally affect your Page Speed because they wouldn't be loaded on page load any more.